# Scroll up a div when scrolling down is finished using one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I searched the solution on stack overflow but i didn't find. That's why i am asking the solution. I am not good in jQuery.

I am working on a site which have a functionality of scrolling down a div with a button. And i did that. Now i want when someone reached at the bottom of the div by clicking the scroll down button, the button turns into a scroll up button and takes him/her at the top of the div.

Below is my scroll down code.

```
<div id="testi-scroll">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec 
</div>

<button class="scroll-up"><img src="gotop-arrow.png" alt="gotop-arrow" /></button>

<script>
var scrolled=0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".scroll-dwn").on("click" ,function(){
    scrolled=scrolled+150;

    jQuery("#testi-scroll").animate({
            scrollTop:  scrolled
       });

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: check dis link "http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/01/03/scrolling-to-the-top-and-bottom-with-jquery/"

Comment: I checked that before but they use one button for scroll up and another button for scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend the `scrolled` variable being initialized to zero and updated as and when the user clicks on the button, because this approach doesn't account for the case when the user clicks and drags the scroll bar instead of using your button.

Here's how I'd tackle the problem. You can find the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Padawan/4o1554m1/2/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".scroll-btn").on('click', function(){

      if($(this).hasClass("scrollup")){
          $("#testi-scroll").animate({
              scrollTop: 0
          }, 200);
          $(this).removeClass("scrollup");
          $(this).text("Scroll Down");
      } else {
          var scrolled = $("#testi-scroll")[0].scrollTop;
          scrolled += 150;

          $("#testi-scroll").animate({
              scrollTop: scrolled
          }, 200);    

          var scrollHeight = $("#testi-scroll")[0].scrollHeight;
          var divHeight = $("#testi-scroll").height();

          if(scrolled >= scrollHeight- divHeight){
              $(this).addClass("scrollup");
              $(this).text("Scroll Up");
          }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works just like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Without your HTML it's hard to give a specific answer for you, but here's a suggestion: Use `.toggleClass` to switch classes for up and down and check if that class exists to figure out if to scroll up or down:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".scroll-btn").on('click', function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('scroll-down')
    if ( jQuery(this).hasClass('scroll-down') ) { 
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#element").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#element").offset().top
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Below is my HTML.

`<div class="testi-area">
     <div id="testi-scroll">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec 
      </div>

      <button class="scroll-up"><img src="gotop-arrow.png" alt="gotop-arrow" /></button>
</div>`